# Back to the line writing in file C language

Tags: c

I got a new line when I'm writing in a file but I don't understand why:

```
for(j = 0; j < p_bdClients->tabClient[i].nbComptes; j++){
    fprintf(p_fichier, "%s %f\n",
        p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].unCompte,
        p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].solde);
}
```

I have:

```
compte1
solde1
compte2
solde2
```

And I'd like to have:

```
compte1 solde1
compte2 solde2
```

I have no newline on `p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].unCompte` or `p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].solde`.

I tried this:

```
for(j = 0; j < p_bdClients->tabClient[i].nbComptes; j++){
   printf("%s\n", p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].unCompte);
}
```

and I got:

```
compte1
compte2
```

But this code:

```
for(j = 0; j < p_bdClients->tabClient[i].nbComptes; j++){
    printf("|%s| %f\n",
        p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].unCompte,
        p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].solde);             
}
```

gives output as -

```
| solde1
| solde2
```

I didn't have the first "|" and `p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].unCompte` I don't understand why.

With:

```
for(j = 0; j < p_bdClients->tabClient[i].nbComptes; j++){
    for(w=0; w<strlen(p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].unCompte); ++w){
        printf("%02hhx ", p_bdClients->tabClient[i].folios[j].unCompte[w]);
}
}
printf("\n");
```

I have:

```
68 79 70 6f 74 68 65 71 75 65 0d 63 68 65 71 75 65 0d 65 70 61 72 67 6e 65 32 0d 
63 68 65 71 75 65 0d 63 61 72 74 65 2d 63 72 65 64 69 74 0d 
68 79 70 6f 74 68 65 71 75 65 0d 63 61 72 74 65 2d 63 72 65 64 69 74 0d 65 70 61 72 67 6e     65 31 0d 63 68 65 71 75 65 0d 65 70 61 72 67 6e 65 32 0d 
63 68 65 71 75 65 0d 63 61 72 74 65 2d 63 72 65 64 69 74 0d 65 70 61 72 67 6e 65 31 0d 
68 79 70 6f 74 68 65 71 75 65 0d 
63 68 65 71 75 65 0d 65 70 61 72 67 6e 65 32 0d
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What are the actual bytes?  Instead of printf("%s\n"), print each byte: for(w=0; w<strlen(...); ++w) printf("%02hhx ", ...[w]);

Comment: Pourquois utiliser %f?

Comment: @JoelFan car c'est un float et non double

Comment: We're not psychic. Post a compilable, reduced test case that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @ant Format flag is the same for floats and doubles ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0x0d at the end of each line (e.g. "68 79 70 6f 74 68 65 71 75 65 **0d**") is a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). Don't store it in `unCompte` (or set it to 0x00) and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe strip newlines (or read data with newlines stripped earlier)? Looks like carriage returns, ASCII 0x0D, visible in hex dump, are not stripped properly. Fix that.

Note that new line in a file may be different combinations of CR (0x0D) and LF (0x0A) ASCII characters, depending on where and how the file was created. LF (Unix) and CR+LF (MS-DOS/Windows) are most common.

In many terminals, printing a CR will move cursor to start of line, and then (without following LF to move to next line) old chars on line will be overwritten, leading to confusing output if this is not intentional.